# gmagick dll vc6 for php5.2

Tags: php, visual-c++-6, pecl

Do you know where I can found the Gmagick.dll (not the Imagick.dll) for php 5.2 in VC6. I do a lot of search but cannot found it in vc6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick

Main site for [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)

Comment: I'm looking for the dll file.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the GraphicsMagick extension for PHP (which provides the class Gmagick in PHP) - not to the generic GraphicsMagick executable (that can be called from the Win command line or through exec() from within PHP)?!

I do not have a source for a VC6 version, but the following link provides at least some VC9 versions:

http://valokuva.org/builds/

To use it your PHP and Apache versions must be compiled with VC9. 
VC9 versions are available for PHP since v5.3 and for Apache since v2.2.